# Print tuple in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I want to print the result of a method which is of type `int * int`.

I tried like this:

```
printf "%d %d\n" (find (99, 10));;
```

However, I'm getting:

```
Error: This expression has type int * int
       but an expression was expected of type int
```

I looked here http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Printf.html but there is no mention of tuple.

So what's the right way to print a tuple?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can detuple it, e.g.,

```
let (x,y) = find (99,10) in 
printf "%d %d\n" x y
```

Alternatively, you can define a tuple printer, e.g.,

```
let pp_int_pair ppf (x,y) =
  fprintf ppf "(%d,%d)" x y
```

and then use it with the `%a` specifier, e.g.,

```
printf "%a\n" pp_int_pair (find (99,10))
```